# How to handle data got from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, annotations, mapkit

I have code like this:

```
ref.child("skelbimai").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        for child in (snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot])!{

            let pinas = PinColorAnotation(color: UIColor.red)
            pinas.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: child.childSnapshot(forPath: "lat").value as! Double, longitude: child.childSnapshot(forPath: "lon").value as! Double)
            pinas.pinColor = Kategorija(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "cat").value as! Int).Color
            pinas.title = String(Kategorija(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "cat").value as! Int).Name)
            pinas.subtitle = String(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "price").value as! Double)
            self.Map.addAnnotation(pinas)
        }

    })
```

Problem is that i cant save my pins to array. I have array Pins = PinColorAnotation,  when i call Pins.append(pinas) and print Pins.count i always get 0. Why is that? but when i call print inside loop its shows 40. Problem is that i have to sort and manage pins later after i downloaded from firebase. but i cant. How to solve that problem? Do i need to do all management logic in :

```
ref.child("skelbimai").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        for child in (snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot])!{

            let pinas = PinColorAnotation(color: UIColor.red)
            pinas.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: child.childSnapshot(forPath: "lat").value as! Double, longitude: child.childSnapshot(forPath: "lon").value as! Double)
            pinas.pinColor = Kategorija(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "cat").value as! Int).Color
            pinas.title = String(Kategorija(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "cat").value as! Int).Name)
            pinas.subtitle = String(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "price").value as! Double)
            self.Map.addAnnotation(pinas)
        }

    })
```

Comment: Firstly, Firebase data is asynchronous, so you would need a completion handler if you want to know when the data has been retrieved. Secondly, when are you instantiating the Map array?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
func getPins(completion: @escaping ([PinColorAnnotation]) -> Void){
  var data: [PinColorAnnotation] = []
  ref.child("skelbimai").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

    for child in (snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot])!{

        let pinas = PinColorAnotation(color: UIColor.red)
        pinas.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: child.childSnapshot(forPath: "lat").value as! Double, longitude: child.childSnapshot(forPath: "lon").value as! Double)
        pinas.pinColor = Kategorija(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "cat").value as! Int).Color
        pinas.title = String(Kategorija(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "cat").value as! Int).Name)
        pinas.subtitle = String(child.childSnapshot(forPath: "price").value as! Double)
        self.data.append(pinas)
    }
    completion(data)
})
}
```

You then call the function wherever you need to, such as `viewDidLoad`. The returned data can then be set to the `self.map` array.

I apologise if there are any mistakes, it has been done on a tablet, as I am not near a computer.

Comment: Thank you very much i didnt know about completion handlers before :D

Comment: You’re welcome! If it worked, please mark the answer as correct.